# What is this constant in my code about?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, addresses

```
modifier onlyOwner() {
    require(msg.sender == address(1111488928422847079491650712165908704041153102605)); 
    _;
}
  
function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256 balance) {
    return balances[_owner];
}
```

What is the address of 11114889284228470791650712165908704041153102605 in the code? Is it encrypted?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You call it *your* code, but you don't know what it says?
To answer though, if you took this code from somewhere, I definitely wouldn't deploy it like that. It appears like someone was trying to hide the actual address

Answer (score 1):

`address(x)` converts `x` to an hexadecimal address. The value in here is obviously not a address.

When you try to convert `11114889284228470791650712165908704041153102605` to hexadecimal, you will see that it corresponds to this address `0xc2b0e326e80c39891fD501d645cA1B8c5d58830d`, which looks like an address.

Edit: Also this approach is not very great. Instead, you should set `owner` variable in constructor to `msg.sender`. Or you can inherit [OpenZeppelin's Ownable contract](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/Ownable.sol).